# How to get integer input for different variables from a single tkinter Entry widget?

Tags: python, events, tkinter, input, tkinter-entry

I’m writing a code for an ecosystem simulation in which the user can adjust initial values as e.g. population size, fertility, and so on. Instead of writing a method for each variable I would like to use a general method that can be called for each variable. I also want to exclude non-integers as input and to restrict the acceptable value to a certain range.

However, the last requirement fails in my code as the range limits for each variable affect each other. Basically because I cannot add arguments to the entry.bind method. How to solve this?

Below, you'll find a simplified version of my code in which the problem happens.

```
import tkinter as tk
class Window():
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Label(master, text ='Fox number').grid(row=0,column=0)
        tk.Label(master, text ='Hare number').grid(row=1,column=0)
        self.fox_entry=tk.Entry(master, width=5)
        self.fox_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.hare_entry=tk.Entry(master, width=5)
        self.hare_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)

class Ecosystem():
    def __init__(self):
        self.foxnumber = 10
        self.harenumber = 100

    def initiate(self):

        def input_user(entry,value, minval, maxval):
            self.value = value
            self.inputvalue = value
            self.minval = minval
            self.maxval = maxval

            def get_value(event):
                try:
                    self.inputvalue = int(entry.get())
                    print(self.inputvalue)
                except ValueError:
                    entry.delete(0,'end')
                    entry.insert(0,self.value)
                    self.inputvalue = self.value
                if self.inputvalue not in range(self.minval, self.maxval+1):
                    entry.delete(0,'end')
                    entry.insert(0,self.value)                     
                    self.inputvalue = self.value
                print(self.inputvalue)

            entry.bind('<Return>', get_value)
            value = self.inputvalue
            return value

        my_win.fox_entry.insert(0,self.foxnumber)
        self.foxnumber = input_user(my_win.fox_entry,self.foxnumber, 0, 50)  

        my_win.hare_entry.insert(0,self.harenumber)
        self.harenumber = input_user(my_win.hare_entry,self.harenumber, 0, 200)
        # more variables will added later on

master = tk.Tk()
my_win = Window()
my_ecosystem = Ecosystem()
my_ecosystem.initiate()
master.mainloop()
```

Comment: `Entry` widget support [validation](https://web.archive.org/web/20190524022302id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/entry-validation.html) via callback functions, which would allow you to enforce the "rules" you want. The Python `re` regular expression module would allow you to parse and extract the (properly-formatted) values from the text it currently contains — if you can't the number you want, then one or more are improperly specified (i.e. non-integer). If you get the expected number, then you can do the range-checking, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, reading the python documentation, it should work. I adapted my code, which became much shorter. However, I get an error message from Python: TypeError: _register() missing 1 required positional argument: 'func'. However, I have put a function in the register method: okay_command = (tk.Entry.register(self.is_okay),'%S') with the def is_okay(self,value) method containing only the statement: return isinstance(value,int) and value >= 0

Comment: I think the problem is you can't pass a regular Python function as the `validatecommand=` argument. Instead you have to register it with `tkinter` using something like `okayCommand = self.register(isOkay)` and the use something like `validatecommand=(okayCommand, '%d', '%i', '%S'), ...)` — as shown in the linked `Entry` documentation.